# Serialize unknown objects with Activiti

Tags: serialization, deserialization, activiti, custom-type

I was reading here: http://blog.progs.be/628/activiti-variables-json about custom ways to serialize an object in Activiti.

I'd like to know if it's possible to create a generic way to serialize with a custom serializer any object from the execution context.

In my scenario there are a lot of dynamic objects whose packages are unknown for me, so I need to find a way to catch the serialization/deserialization process to handle the content which is going to stored in the database.

Is this possible?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you meam by "dynamic objects" in your case? If Are they groovy/JavaScript objects you can use json as the external format. If by "dynamic" you mean a java pojo, and you want to get back objects of the same kind when you deserialize them from the database, then you can use xml and jaxb as your externalization mechanism.